# how to get stored procedure text with parameter after execution?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have this stored procedure

```
 create proc ins (@val1 nvarchar(50), @val2 nvarchar(50))
 as
 insert into mytable values (@val1,@val2)
 --======================================================
 exec ins(1,2)
```

Now i need to get stored procedure text with replacement value 
like the following

```
 insert into mytable values (1,2)
```

Comment: You're question is vague, where do you want to use the stored procedure text? In a C# program I guess? Then how do you access the database? Entity framework? If you add more information your question is much more likely to get an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a string variable after insert line and then select that variable

```
insert into mytable values (@val1,@val2)

DECLARE @res as nvarchar(200)
set @res = N"insert into mytable 
values (" + @val1 + N"," + @val2 +N")"
SELECT @res
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the <kbd>[`OUTPUT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx)</kbd> clause inside your store procedure to get the inserted values.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ins 
@val1 nvarchar(50), 
@val2 nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

   DECLARE @rtn_Table TABLE (val1 nvarchar(50), val2 nvarchar(50))

 INSERT INTO  mytable (Col1, Col2)
 OUTPUT inserted.Col1, inserted.Col2 INTO @TABLE
 VALUES (@val1,@val2)


  SELECT * FROM @TABLE

END
```

**Execute Procedure**

```
DECLARE @Var1 NVARCHAR(50);
DECLARE @Var2 NVARCHAR(50);

SET @Var1 = 'value1';
SET @Var2 = 'value2';

DECLARE @r_Table TABLE (val1 nvarchar(50), val2 nvarchar(50));

INSERT INTO @r_Table (val1, val2)
EXECUTE dbo.ins @Var1, @Var2

SELECT * FROM @r_Table
```